# Scala, Play Framework - "JsUndefined("VALUE1" is not an object)" - is there a better way to deserialise json into Map[String, String]?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, deserialization, play-json

I have a Json request body that represents four key-value pairs. I am attempting to deserialise the Json body (a `JsValue` object) into a Map of Strings, `Map[String, String]`, but I get the following error:

*"JsUndefined("VALUE1" is not an object)"*.

**Json example:**

```json
{
    "key1":"VALUE1",
    "key2":"VALUE2",
    "key3":"VALUE3",
    "key4":"VALUE4"
}
```

**Deserialization example:**

```
val jsonResult = request.body //type of JsValue
(jsonResult \ "KEY1" \ "KEY2" \ "KEY3" \ "KEY4").asOpt[Map[String, String]]
```

It seems that attempting to extract the key-value pairs with the above line does not work, and that doing them indivudually does actually work E.g:

```
val keyPair1 = (jsonResult \ "KEY1")
val keyPair2 = (jsonResult \ "KEY2")
```

**Question**

Is there a way to deserialize each key-value pair in the provided JSON, represented as a `JsValue`, into a `Map[String, String]` all at once?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that every time you do `\`, you access the next key in the path. For example, when doing:

```
jsonResult \ "KEY1" \ "KEY2" \ "KEY3" \ "KEY4"
```

you are trying to access the path:

```
KEY1.KEY2.KEY3.KEY4
```

which, does not exist in the provided json.

The path `KEY1`, has `JsString("VALUE1")`, and does not have a descendant, therefore you get the error mentioned above.

Instead, you can simply do:

```scala
val jsonString = """{
                   |    "key1":"VALUE1",
                   |    "key2":"VALUE2",
                   |    "key3":"VALUE3",
                   |    "key4":"VALUE4"
                   |}""".stripMargin

val json = Json.parse(jsonString).asOpt[Map[String, String]]
println(json)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/x6KI3bVzQGeTMwJlYsFqmg).

Comment: I'm starting with a `JsValue` Object. Even when I `toString()` the JsValue, and then pass that String into your code Snippet, a match statement I have on the 'json' variable (the Option[Map[String, String]]) never matches the Some(_) case, only the None case.

Comment: @Chris did you see the code snippet I added? Can you please create one of your own that reproduces your issue?